# Google Play Services Ad Doesn't collapse if there is no ad

Tags: android

I was trying to implement Google play services Ad instead of AdMob.

But unlike the Admob AdView, this adview shows a blank rectangle before loading the ad and takes the valuable screen space if there is no ad.

How to fix it?

This is my code

```
AdView adView = (AdView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(id);
     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID").build();
     adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the AdView's visibility to GONE initially.

```
adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Then set an AdListener on the AdView. In the onAdLoaded() callback you can set the AdView's visibility to VISIBLE.

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```